# Have only one Apache running on macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, apache, homebrew

Via *brew* I installed an Apache Server with `PHP 7.4` running, however it seems that there are two servers and two different PHP versions running.

On `localhost` `phpinfo()` shows `7.4` however on `127.0.0.1` `phpinfo()` shows `7.3`
The `localhost` `phpinfo()` shows it's running on brew, however on `127.0.0.1` it seems that the built-in Apache is running, it shows `Built-in HTTP server`

Stopping Apache via `sudo apachectl stop` stops the brew one from working (`localhost`), but the built-in (`127.0.0.1`) is still running it seems.

`which -a apachectl` shows

```
/usr/local/bin/apachectl
/usr/sbin/apachectl
```

Any tips on how to stop the built-in one and only have the brew one running are gladly welcomed!

Thx!